# Serialization and Deserialization of Struct in C/C++

Tags: c++, serialization, struct, deserialization

I have a struct like:

```
typedef struct myStruct
 {

                int attr;
                 char *name;
                 size_t nameSize;

 }
```

I want to serialize it and the serialize it. I found answers but all of them were using a more simple structure (no pointers). Also, in my function, I must receive a pointer to the structure, not the struct itself. So I can't use sizeof.

How can I serialize this into a buffer so I can later deserialize it?

```
int serializeData(myStruct *componentInfo, void *buffer, size_t bufferSize, size_t *result)
{

    int dataSize = 0;
    dataSize += sizeof(int);
    dataSize += strlen(componentInfo->name);
    dataSize += sizeof(size_t);
    char data[dataSize+1];

    int offset =0;
    memcpy(data, &componentInfo->attr, sizeof(int));
    offset+=sizeof(int);

    memcpy(data + offset, &componentInfo->nameSize, sizeof(size_t));
    offset+= sizeof(size_t);

    memcpy(data + offset, componentInfo->name, componentInfo->nameSize);
    offset+= componentInfo->nameSize;

    printf("%s",data);
    printf("a    %zu",strlen(data));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "_Also, in my function, I must receive a pointer to the structure, not the struct itself. So I can't use sizeof._" That doesn't make sense. There's nothing stopping you from doing `sizeof myStruct`.

Comment: What's the problem? Write out `attr`, write out `nameSize`, write out the data that `name` is pointing at . Do the reverse on reading. I am assuming that `nameSize` tells you how much data `name` is pointing at.

Comment: Only if you think that you should be able to do this in one line of code are you going to have any problems.

Comment: Yes nameSize tells how much data is in name. I was thinking maybe I should keep the data in order. Seems not. Also, first I must put the bytes into a buffer. Is memcpy the way to go?

Comment: `memcpy` seems reasonable to me. You are making the assumption that the *endianess* will be the same for reading and writing, but I guess that's not an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing. First I do memcpy(buffer, &struc->attr,sizeof(int)). Then I do memcpy(buffer + sizeof(int), &struc->nameSize, sizeof(size_t)). Third I do memcpy(buffer + sizeof(int) + sizeof(size_t), &struc->name,struc->nameSize). But when I try to print the buffer (the buffer is char[]) I only get 1 random byte.

Comment: Please add the serialization code to the question. Also how do you print your buffer? Because cout << buffer will not really work because many binary smbols are not printable and it will stop at the first null symbol anyways. Also hope you are aware that the loaded pointer will be useless if you stop the program and restart it, or if the associated array is freed.

Comment: @AlexGeorg added serialization code. Technically I have to put the data in the void* buffer I get in the function. I put it into a char* to avoid some warnings.

Comment: @Ernesto98 You can just memcopy the whole struct too because the struct encompasses the memory for all three member variables and sizeof is aplicable to the struct too (you might be surprised by the result being larger than your sum however - that is because of "aliasing"). However as mentioned, your way of debugging by printing is not suited for binary data. And did you expect to have the name printed too? That will not work because your data array only contains the bytes of the pointer to that name.

Comment: I need to have the actual name into the buffer. If I just memcpy the struct wouldn't it simply copy the pointer?

Comment: Your code is C-only. No C++. You could use C++ to do your task. Then you can simply insert all data into a stream (whatever) and later extract it fom there.